# Excel VBA: Call absolute cell from dynamic reference

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a worksheet where a code is found in Column `A`, then the macro offsets the row reference and copies it back to another sheet.

I would like to change this so that the macro looks through a range of columns, say columns `A` to `E`, finds the code then looks along the row to pick up from Column `F`, then so on.

This is my code as it stands; this obviously only works for one code column as it uses `Offset`. I should also point out that there could be codes in columns `A`, `B`, `C` and/or `D`, so finding the next blank cell won't work.

```
''code above here for rest of macro
'' ws refers to the destination worksheet
''c is the code, in this case in column A but will be in columns A, B, C or D
ws.Range("A" & lastRow) = c.Offset(, 1)
ws.Range("B" & lastRow) = c.Offset(, 2)
'' code below to continue similarly
```

Hope this makes sense!

---

Title edited to 'absolute cell'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something using the `.Row`

for example

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A")
```

this will go to column `A` in the same row, which is the same as a column offset but you can go to column `A` from any column without having multiple `offset`

edit

```
testc = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(code).address
Range(testc).Select

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B").Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastrow)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried to add it to to sheet like so `ws.Range("A" & lastRow) = c.Cells(c.Row, "B")` but it doesn't pick up the correct code from column A. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't explain it in my question. `c` is set as `c = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(code)`  which finds the correct row, then finds the data in column `B` and copies it to `ws.Range("A" & lastRow)`. does this make sense?

Comment: Changing it around, I now get the code _above_ the one I need with this:  `ws.Range("A" & lastRow) = c.Cells(ActiveRow, "B")`. Is this for some reason calling lastRow as well? thanks very much for your help @ballsy26

Comment: i've added additional information to the answer, i think it should work but it is quite a messy solution to the problem

Comment: I get an `Object variable or With block variable not set` error on the first line... am I doing something really obviously wrong?

Comment: replace that line of code with the code you are using to find `c`

Comment: yes, I did that.... I set `Dim testc As Range` as well - that's where I went wrong. It works, but it's still finding the wrong code! Sorry :( Is it something to do with the `ActiveCell Row`?

Comment: so right now what code does it copy? it should copy the code from the same row in column B and put it in the last row

Comment: yes it should but it copies the code from column b in the row above the correct one. :(

Comment: Super ghetto but try changing it to `sheets("sheet1"). Cells(activecell.row, "b").offset(1,0).copy`

Comment: that's worked - thanks, just the only thing is it then selects the same row on the destination sheet as the code was on the source sheet??? I have no idea why

Comment: That's probably because it of the `range(testc).select` that's actually selecting a cell. Not 100% sure though